# How to get the user check in information from facebook account?

Tags: xcode, facebook

http://tylerwhitedesign.com/how-to-check-in-using-the-facebook-ios-sdk-and-graph-api
every where only this link is showing ,but using this we get only near by locations .
I want is how to get the checkin information from FB account to our application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean this links?

Here you can see a full list: 
[Facebook Field values](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Here you can send a test messages for test a response data:
[Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=100002032887359?fields=id,name)